# Sort the properties based on base classes and attribute order

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggling to get this done

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int baseint { get; set; }
}

public class Dervied : BaseClass
{
    public int Derviedint { get; set; }
}

public class DemoClass : Dervied
{
    [Test(order=2)]
    public int Demoint { get; set; }

    [Test(order=1)]
    public string Demostring { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want list of properties in sorted order like 
`List<PropertyInfo> sorted = List<PropertyInfo>()`. Now this list should contain 
the following

- Baseint
- Derviedint
- Demostring
- Demoint

`List<PropertyInfo> info = o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();`

This is giving me a list of properties. But not exactly what I wanted. 
Here is an object which is sent at run time.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `o` is not necessary.  You can get the type simply by using `typeof(DemoClass)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by crawling the list of `BaseType`s on `DemoClass`, inspecting the `DeclaringType` property of your `PropertyInfo`s, and getting the `Test` attribute:

```
void Main()
{
    var t = typeof(DemoClass);
    var typeTree = GetTypeTree(t);
    List<PropertyInfo> info = typeof(DemoClass)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .OrderByDescending(x => typeTree.IndexOf(x.DeclaringType))
        .ThenBy(GetOrderNumber).ToList();

    foreach (var prop in info)
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}

int? GetOrderNumber(PropertyInfo prop) {
    var attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>(true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (attr != null)
        return attr.order;
    else
        return null;
}

IList<Type> GetTypeTree(Type t) {
    var types = new List<Type>();
    while (t.BaseType != null) {
        types.Add(t);
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
    return types;
}
```

You could have used the [`DeclaredOnly` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and gotten the properties for each class in order, but I think this way is a little easier to understand.

Comment: I think this hits everything the OP asked for.

Comment: It worked like charm. If u were in front of me i would have hugged you. It was around 2 Am in morning still struggling. Finally Got it. Truly you are my hero for the day.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat expanded example - you could condense it down some if needed, but in this form it's a little easier to see what's going on.

```
var o = new DemoClass();
var properties = o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();
var propertiesWithAttributes = 
    properties.Select(property => 
        new
        {
            Property = property,
            Attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
        });
var sorted =
    propertiesWithAttributes
    .OrderBy(pwa => pwa.Attribute != null ? pwa.Attribute.order : int.MaxValue);
```